# My previous version of Tor transfers torrents to Vuze - updated Tor will not

Tags: help

After updating, when I click on the torrent link for the download (piratebay for example) it will not send it to Vuze. How can I set it up please?

Comment: What was your "old" version, and what is the "updated" version number?

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of the Tor Browser to prevent accidentally leaking TBB information to an exteral program that isn't configured to use Tor.

From https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/5556 titled "magnet uri support"

> This is supported in Firefox, this does not work in Tor.
>   Simply put, this is not a Mozilla issue, nor is it a Firefox issue, this is a Tor Browser issue.
>   As per the original description: When clicking magnet:// prefixed links, "The browser does ask for permission to open the associated application. The associated application never recieves the message from the TBB. This works in normal Firefox.